# Place a grid onto polygons in shapefile and then find centroid of each grid square

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sf

I have a shapefile of polygons, that I would like to partition into smaller polygons by overlaying a grid.  Then I would like to find the centroid of each of these smaller polygons created by the grid.

My dataframe is:

```
df<-structure(list(shape = c(1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 
4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 6.1, 6.1, 6.1, 6.1, 7.1, 7.1, 7.1, 7.1, 8.1, 8.1, 
8.1, 8.1, 9.1, 9.1, 9.1, 9.1), longitude = c(43, 43, 40, 40, 23, 23, 20, 20, 25, 25, 38, 38, 
25,25, 38, 38, 45, 50, 50, 45, 65, 60, 60, 65, 60, 60, 80, 80, 60, 60, 80, 80, 20, 20, 80, 
80), latitude = c(10, 13, 13, 10, 10, 13, 13, 10, 10, 10.3, 10.3, 10, 12.7, 13, 13, 12.7, 
13, 13, 10, 10, 13, 13, 10, 10, 9.8, 9.5, 9.5, 9.8, 6, 5.7, 5.7, 6, 5, 4.5, 4.5, 5)), 
row.names = c(NA, 36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then I convert the dataframe into a shapefile as follows:

```
area <- lapply(split(df, df$shape), function(x) { coords <- as.matrix(cbind(x$longitude, 
                                                                       x$latitude)); 
list(rbind(coords, coords[1,]))}) 

names(area) <-  NULL

Coord_Ref <-  st_crs(4326)
area <-  st_sfc(st_multipolygon(x=area), crs = Coord_Ref)
area <-  st_cast(area, "POLYGON")
```

Then I place a grid over the polygons and plot it:

```
plot(st_make_grid(area, cellsize=0.5))
```

[image]

I know how to find the centroid of polygons using st_centroid function:

```
st_centroid(area)
```

However, Is it best to do this in a way that does not use st_centroid? I receive the warning 'st_centroid does not give correct centroids for longitude/latitude data'.  Or is it okay to ignore this warning as I am dealing with small areas?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your question, but can't you just do st_centroid(st_make_grid(area, cellsize=0.5))) to get the centroids of the grid?

Comment: It is somewhat unclear from your question; but if you have a problem with running `sf::st_centroid()` on unprojected (spherical) coordinates you can easily project them to a planar CRS via `sf::st_transform()` - the CRS for this would depend on your area of interest.

Comment: You can simplify your polygon creation with `area <- sfheaders::sfc_polygon( obj = df, x = "longitude", y = "latitude", polygon_id = "shape"
);  sf::st_crs( area ) <- 4326`

Comment: My question was not clearly worded.  Is it okay to ignore the warning that st_centroid does not give correct centroids for longitude/latitude data? Is it necessary to project to planar?

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for the GIS stackexhange, since it's more a question about working with projected/unprojected data than something necessarily specific to r/sf. That said, the comments in this link might be helpful. Sounds like if you want uniformly grid cells, you'd be better off projecting your data first. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306198/creating-1km-square-grid?noredirect=1&lq=1